# Why does my logging setup for GRPC in .NET Core fail to output to the console?

Tags: c#, .net-core, logging, grpc

I have the following configuration in my appsettings.Development.json in a console application:

```
{
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Debug",
            "System": "Information",
            "Microsoft": "Information",
            "Grpc" : "Debug"
        }
    }
}
```

My main program, to test GPRC calls indirectly via the Google.Cloud.SecretManager.V1, is as follows:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var client = SecretManagerServiceClient.Create();
                var result = client.AccessSecretVersion(new SecretVersionName("some-project-id", "some_secret_key", "latest"));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               Console.WriteLine(ex); 
            }
        }
    }
```

When I debug the application I get no logs despite having the following environment variable setup:

```
GRPC_TRACE=all
GRPC_VERBOSITY=DEBUG
```

I would expect logging via the console output

I've been using the following pages as reference:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/diagnostics?view=aspnetcore-3.1
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

What have I missed?

For the wider context, this problem arises from trying to troubleshoot [a GRPC issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/8315)

Comment: Could I suggest that you start simpler, with just a console application? Note that Grpc.Core doesn't automatically integrate with `ILogger` so that's probably why you're not seeing the logs. A console app which just makes a single request is going to be much easier to work with than a web app.

Comment: Hi @JonSkeet thanks for reponse. I've updated to describe the suggested setup. Still getting the same issue.

Comment: Your code doesn't configure logging at all. Adding the configuration settings won't add the logging middleware packages to your application or configure logging sinks. The second article you link to uses the Generic Host which also adds logging

Comment: Your question now has an appsettings.json file which is usually for web apps, links to the Microsoft documentation which is aimed at Grpc.Net.Client (rather than Grpc.Core which the client library uses by default) and a console app. I suspect *just* the console app would be more productive and less confusing. If you run your console app from a console with those environment variables set, you really should get gRPC logging, starting with something like "D0406 11:45:26.420366 Grpc.Core.Internal.UnmanagedLibrary Attempting to load native library"

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes this was created as a console application after your first suggestion. In my ignorance I thought I needed an `appsettings.json` but it works now. More detail about the nature of my oversight in answer. Lots of output to inspect.

Answer (score 0):

My misunderstanding was that the appsettings file is simply not required for a console application. I also don't need to configure any custom logging in a method like `ConfigureServices`.

All I needed to do was setup the environment variables correctly. I did configure these variables for my user in windows but strangely they were not being picked up by Rider.

Once I configured these variables in Rider in the debug settings I got the output needed.

Anyone having a similar issue should double check that their IDE is really picking up the variables and if necessary specify them in the application run.

Alternatively you could just run the console application executable directly and avoid the trap I fell into.

Comment: "I did configure these variables for my user in windows but strangely they were not being picked up by Rider." I suspect you started Rider before changing the environment variables. (This is why I tend to open a console, set the environment variables there, and execute the code there too...)